# how to copy list of models to new list in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, model

I am facing an issue where I cant copy a list of models to new list with an easy way.

What I want to achieve is:

```
List<Package> event_packages = [...]; // list with data here
List<Package> packages = List.from(event_packages);
```

The issue now is whenever I edit some data in the packages, event packages get edited too. I believe because it copies the object references.

Solution so far is:

```
List<Package> packages = [];
event_packages.forEach((package) { 
   packages.add(Package.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(package))));
});
```

But seems very hacky and slow.

**What is the right way to do this?**

Comment: If you want to perform a clone of an instance of `Package`, going via JSON is certainly one way. Of course, there's nothing preventing from writing a different named constructor (e.g. `Package.from(Package other)`) that copies over whatever it needs from `other` to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't believe there is a simple method to do what you want, what I recommend is making a constructor that copies the data from one package to another but depending on what exactly package is, that might be not possible?

```
class Package {

  Package({this.title='', this.age=0, this.height=0});

  Stirng title;
  int age
  double height;

  // here
  factory Package.fromPackage(Package other) {
    return Package(title: other.title, age: other.age, height: other.height);
  }
}
```

Then when making the second list:

```
List<Package> event_packages = [...]; // list with data here
List<Package> packages = event_packages.map((pckg) => Package.fromPackage(pckg)).toList();
```

Comment: I am using this factory "Package.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> item) => _$PackageFromJson(item);"  with JsonSerializable

Answer (score -1):

You can copy a new List with the following code:

```
List<Package> event_packages = [...]; // list with data here
List<Package> packages = [];
packages.addAll(event_packages);
```

Comment: it copies the object references, and any edits you make in packages will also apply to event_packages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).